# Losing (-- select--) from the list after binding data to the dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Losing  (--Select--) from  dropdownlist after binding data

```
 List<string> state = new List<string>();
        state = Details.getstate(country);
        ddl_State.DataSource = state;
        ddl_State.DataBind();
```

Comment: In your markdown for the dropdownlist, set `AppendDataBoundItems="True"`.  This will append any items that are databound.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have --Select-- defined in your markup, like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_State" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can use the `AppendDataBoundItems` attribute to add items when binding data without clearing the already declared items:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_State" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Note that I've left out a lot of markup - this is just to give the general concept.

[ListControl.AppendDataBoundItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx)